# Xcode 4: spell checking only in comments?

Tags: xcode, spell-checking

I would like to enable spelling checking only for comments and to forbid it for "code" section. Is it possible for XCode 4?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Applesupport:
Hello username,

This is a follow up to Bug ID# 9503087.  After further investigation it has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.  This issue has been filed in our bug database under the original Bug ID# 9262217. The original bug number being used to track this duplicate issue can be found in the State column, in this format:  Duplicate/OrigBug#.

Thank you for submitting this bug report. We truly appreciate your assistance in helping us discover and isolate bugs.

Best Regards,

Developer Support
Apple Worldwide Developer Relations

Comment: Seems they didn't fixed it yet, with 4.5.2 version. After almost 2 years. Probably they consider it a feature by now...

Comment: Make that six years at least now. It's such a basic feature I don't understand how Apple has decided it's not important

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor infront of you comment and press **cmd+;** this will jump to the next misspelt word.